# Convert Dates in Powershell but Format Not Recognized

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use powershell to convert a string that contains RFC 2822 formatted dates into another format. Right now I'm getting an error saying my string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
Write-Host ([Datetime]::ParseExact('Thu Oct 07 09:23:26 UTC 2021', '[R][1]', $null)).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what format pattern does `R` give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `R` standard datetime format string specifier does *not* describe the format you've supplied.

You're gonna need a custom format string:

```
[Datetime]::ParseExact('Thu Oct 07 09:23:26 UTC 2021', 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss UTC yyyy', $null)
```